# Optimal time for sleichos

Tags: zemanim, selichot

What is the optimal time for the recitation of, nay the asking for, Sleichos? Please state whose opinion you are following or stating in your answer.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9607 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10243.

Answer (score 2):

[Orach Chaim 581:1 and Mishna Berura intro](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14166&st=&pgnum=105) say the optimal time for Selichos is early morning (Ashmaros HaBoker) since that is an Eis Ratzon.