# saying selichos motzai shabbas

Tags: evening-night, selichot, motzei-shabbos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why only on the first Saturday night of Selichot is the minhag to start at midnight?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10243/why-only-on-the-first-saturday-night-of-selichot-is-the-minhag-to-start-at-midni)

Where does the minhag come from to say the first selichos on motzai shabbas when one can say it the next morning?

If night is more preferable why not say it at night the whole week?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10243/759

Comment: @DoubleAA seems like an exact duplicate. Am I missing something?

Comment: @msh210 Hmm not sure. My question was 1st Saturday night vs 2nd Saturday night. His is about 1st Saturday night vs every other night.

Comment: @DoubleAA that question was "Some say at chatzot all week and some in the morning. Why davka on the first night does everyone say at night?", which is this question AFAICT.

Comment: See also related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9607/saying-selichos-before-midnight

Comment: @msh210 I guess you are right. I certainly meant to ask what I said in my above comment but it seems I wasn't clear/precise enough.